# triple equals gives wrong output when strings are compared, but in case of integer it gives correct output

Tags: javascript, equality

I have an array of string like

`var a = ['a','a','a'];`

When I do comparison like `a[0]==a[1]==a[2]` it gives me result as `false`
but when I change the value of array to `['1','1','1']` and do the same comparison like above the result will be`true`.

Again when I change the input to `['9','9','9']` then above comparison is giving me result as `false`.

Can anybody tell me the reason behind this behaviour in javascript ?

Comment: That's invalid, doing a triple comparison like that.

Comment: Could you clarify, you said "triple equals" implying `===` in title but only use double equals `==` in code

Comment: @phuzi probably means "equals between three variables" as opposed to "using `===`"

Comment: @JackBashford it's definitely *valid*. It just doesn't produce what OP thinks it does.

Comment: `a==b==c` means `(a == b) == c` in your case: `('a' == 'a') == 'a'` or `true == 'a'` which is `false`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
a[0]==a[1] && a[0]==a[2]
```

In your case, when you are comparing ['1','1','1'], what happening is

```
a[0] == a[1]  // true
true == a[2]  // true as true == '1'
```

Comment: That's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand if you test the inner value direct:
`0==0==0` is understood as `(0==0)==0`, so `0==0` is `true`, what's tested next is `(true)==0`, `0` is interpreted as `false`, and `true==false` is `false`.

For the other comparisons the first part is the same, but `1` or `9` are interpreted as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that it executes it like this:

```
 ((a[0]==a[1])==a[2]):
```

1.

```
(a[0] == a[1]) => true
```

2.

```
(true == a[2]) => false
```

Because: `1 == true`, the array [1,1,1] returns true

Answer (score 0):

This is expected output

```
// Case 1
var a = ['a','a','a'];

The output of 

a[0] == a[1] --> true

Next Comparison

true == a[2] --> false // true != 'a';

// Case 2

var a = ['1','1','1'] ;

a[0] == a[1] --> true

true == a[2] --> true // true == "1"
```

However, in case 2 if you use `strict equality` operator then the result will be false.

```js
var a = ['1','1','1'] ;

// strict equality operator
console.log(a[0]===a[1]===a[2]);

// without strict equality operator
console.log(a[0]==a[1]==a[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of operator `==` it is `left-to-right`. So in your case

when 
`var a = ['a','a','a'];
a[0]==a[1]==a[2]` this evaluate `a[0]==a[1]` first then result of this with `a[3]` means `true == 'a'` which returns `false`.

In case when `var a = ['1','1','1'];` so as per associativity this evaluates from left to right in expression `a[0]==a[1]==a[2]` results `'1' == '1'` in first, then `true == '1'` in second which gives `true` finally.

In case when `var a = ['9','9','9'];` first `'9' == '9'` then `true == '9'` which finally evaluates to false. Hope this helps.