# Why the switch statement doesn't give an output?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a problem with this statement I didn't understand where the problem is

```
console.log(typeof moyen);
switch(moyen) {
    case (10 < moyen < 11.99):
    console.log("Acceptable");
    case (12 < moyen < 13):
    console.log("Souhaitable"); 
    case (14 < moyen < 15):
    console.log("Bien");
    case (moyen >= 16):
    console.log("Très bien");
    default:
    ("C'est pas un valide moyen !");
};
```

it doesn't give any output, please show me where the problem is and thanks in advance

Comment: `10 < moyen < 11.99` doesn't do what you probably think it does. It's `(10 < moyen) < 11.99` so you're eventually comparing a boolean to a number.

Comment: check this 
default:
    ("C'est pas un valide moyen !");

Comment: this is basically the same problem as in this question from a few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770800/triple-equals-gives-wrong-output-when-strings-are-compared-but-in-case-of-integ

Comment: `break` statement is missing.

Comment: what is `moyen` here?

Comment: You should probably re-read how switch/case works. The switch expression is evaluated once (in your case - the result is the value of `moyen`). Then that result is compared (for equality) with each expression in the `case` statements in turn. So your code is comparing the value of `moyen` with the result of `(10 < moyen < 11.99`) - which probably isn't going to do much that's useful.

Comment: what about missing ranges?

Comment: @Dood good question. I completely missed this is doing `switch(moyen)`. So this only works if `moyen` is `true` and (at least) all but one of the comparisons is `false` or `moyen` is `false` and (at least) all but one of the comparisons is `true`. However, since `moyen` is *also* part of the comparisons, it appears to intended as some sort of number. So, this code can never really work unless the code bends over backwards to try to accommodate what shouldn't be.

Comment: @VLAZ even when i use (10 < moyen && moyen < 11.99) it doesn't give any output

Comment: Yes, that's true thank you so much, in this case we should use the if statement right ? but it makes to code more longer, is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code

1. you have conditions in your case, which will return boolean. so you have to pass boolean in switch
2. you missed break statement
3. you missed to print or do anything in default statement

```js
var moyen = 9;

switch(true) {
    case (10 < moyen && moyen < 11.99):
    console.log("Acceptable");
    break;
    case (12 < moyen && moyen < 13):
    console.log("Souhaitable"); 
    break;
    case (14 < moyen && moyen < 15):
    console.log("Bien");
    break;
    case (moyen >= 16):
    console.log("Très bien");
    break;
    default:
    console.log("C'est pas un valide moyen !");
};
```

Comment: There is no need for `break` in `default`. It's superfluous, as there is nothing further to fallthrough to.

Answer (score 4):

Beside the missing [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), you could take a lower range and exit. Then check the given smaller value, finally take default for greater values.

```
switch(true) {
    case moyen <= 10:
        console.log("C'est pas un valide moyen !");
        break;
    case moyen < 12:
        console.log("Acceptable");
        break;
    case moyen < 13:
        console.log("Souhaitable"); 
        break;
    case moyen < 15:
        console.log("Bien");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Très bien");
};
```

Comment: I think `case moyen <= 10:` should be the first case.